# Stacked/Consecutive Genitives

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax

For example, *the way of the cross* in Latin is *via crucis*, but how would one go about saying *the beginning of the way of the cross*? Would both *via* and *crux* be in the genitive, yielding *principium viae crucis*? Is this usually how consecutive genitive constructions are formed?

Comment: Welcome to the site - great question!

Comment: An alternative can be to render one of the "of"s as an adjective, e.g. *principium viae crucialis*. I suspect the Romans would consider too many (how many?) genitives ugly. Religious texts might care less.

Comment: @Cerberus I feel like that would make a great question of its own of the Latin Community of Stack Exchange.

Comment: The most famous “stacked” genetive is probably the papal title *Servus servorum Dei* ([Servant of the servants of God](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Catholic_Encyclopedia_(1913)/Servus_servorum_Dei)).

Answer (score 7):

A genetive depending on another genetive is relatively rare, and traditonally grammarians taught that it should be avoided; however, that is sometimes difficult to do, and so double (and triple) genetives can occasionally be found in the best prose writers.

For example:

> patimur hebescere aciem horum auctoritatis
> *we let the edge of their decree become blunt*

(Cicero, In Catilinam 1,4)

> neque alia ulla fuit causa intermissionis epistularum nisi quod ubi esses plane nesciebam
> *and there was no reason for the pause in my letters other than that I had no idea where you were*

(Cicero, Ad Familiares 7,13)

And the famous German grammarian [Karl Gottlob Zumpt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Gottlob_Zumpt) [writes](https://books.google.de/books?id=6JhEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA359#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Und es fällt bei Livius in der *praef.* nicht eben auf, zu lesen: *juvabit me ipsum consuluisse memoriae **rerum gestarum principis terrarum populi***
> And it does not particularly stand out to read this from Livius in the *praefatio*: [⋯]

(Check the Google Books link! Someone wrote in the margin: “It does not?”)

That's a triple genetive: the account of the history of the most distinguished nation of the earth.

Zumpt recommends to avoid multiple genetives only where it would lead to ambiguity. His negative example: *magna erat multitudo spectatorum ornamentorum fanorum*. Were the people who looked at the temples richly bejewelled? Or did lots of people look at the trappings of the temples? It is the latter, so Zumpt recommends: *multitudo eorum, qui ornamenta fanorum spectabant*.

Answer (score 3):

Stacking genitives is usually avoided, though it is grammatical.

I originally gave the example of stacking genitives as “for the sake of loving my dog”: “Canis mei amandi causa”, but as @Sebastian Koppehel pointed out, while my example was correct, it was not stacking genitives. *Canis mei* agrees with *amandi* and therefore this construction works, but here *amandi* is a gerund, a verbal adjective, and *not* a verbal noun like I intended it to be. If *amandi* were a noun, it actually would take an accusative and not a genitive, and we'd see *Canem meum amandi causa*.

Sometimes adjectives are used instead of genitives as discussed in [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/what-is-the-difference-between-an-adjective-ending-in-alis-and-a-genitive-in-p), answered in detail by @Joonas Ilmavirta. While it's true that an adjective might sometimes be best to avoid stacking genitives, I would say in the specific case of “crux”, the genitive is best. The root of *crux* usually carries a sense of torment or torture. *Via cruciaria* might sound like “Torturous path”, which is not, I assume, what you want to be saying.

I hope I’ve answered your question well, and welcome to the sight!

Comment: *Canis mei amandi causa* ← I think that's just agreement. You would also say *in cane amando* (and not *canis*).

Comment: That's a fair point actually. I'll have to edit this answer. I happened to give a grammatically correct answer, but not for the reasons I thought. I construed this as genitive gerundive + objective genitive, but I've now realized that gerundives do not take objective genitives.